# Android SDK 3.0: requesting publish perimissoins causes login again

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

When I'm trying o request publish permissions after login via facebook dialog (no fb app is installed) I'm asked to login again, and after that everything is running normally. Is there any way to avoid this problem? Here is my code:

```
private void login() {
        Session.Builder builder = new Session.Builder(activity);
        builder.setApplicationId(activity.getString(R.string.app_id));
        builder.setTokenCachingStrategy(new SharedPreferencesTokenCachingStrategy(activity));
        Session session = builder.build();

        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        Session.OpenRequest request = new Session.OpenRequest(activity).setCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (exception!=null) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (session.isOpened())
                    checkAndRequestPermissions();
            }
        });
        session.openForRead(request);
    }

private void checkAndRequestPermissions() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (!session.getPermissions().contains(USER_PHOTOS_PERMISSION))
            permissionsList.add(USER_PHOTOS_PERMISSION);
        if (!session.getPermissions().contains(PUBLISH_ACTIONS_PERMISSION))
            permissionsList.add(PUBLISH_ACTIONS_PERMISSION);
        if (permissionsList.size()>0) {
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest request = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(activity, permissionsList);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(request);
        }
        else {
            publishOnFacebook(filesToPublish);
        }
    }
```

Comment: see my answer for a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244866)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've figured out how to request both read and publish permissions. You should use Session.openForPublish method:

```
        Session.Builder builder = new Session.Builder(activity);
        builder.setApplicationId(activity.getString(R.string.app_id));
        builder.setTokenCachingStrategy(new SharedPreferencesTokenCachingStrategy(activity));
        Session session = builder.build();

        List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (!session.getPermissions().contains(USER_PHOTOS_PERMISSION))
            permissionsList.add(USER_PHOTOS_PERMISSION);
        if (!session.getPermissions().contains(PUBLISH_ACTIONS_PERMISSION))
            permissionsList.add(PUBLISH_ACTIONS_PERMISSION);

        Session.OpenRequest request = new Session.OpenRequest(activity).setCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (exception!=null) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (session.isOpened())
                    checkAndRequestPermissions();
            }
        });
        request.setPermissions(permissionsList);
        request.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
        session.openForPublish(request);
```

And everything works fine for me